# Where do I find the AC power draw?

Tags: kernel, power-management, bios

My `sysfs` has details on current, voltage etc under the battery node `/sys/class/power_supply/BATn`. However, under the `AC` node, none of these details are available.

I'd like to know how to go about determining what the problem is,

- Doesn't the hardware provide the data?
- Do I lack a kernel module?
- Some detail lacking in BIOS?
- Any other questions that should be asked?

My kernel is 5.12.6 (archlinux)

Comment: A friend reports the same on a ubuntu @ 5.8.0.

Comment: Yes, I would also like to have this, but it's probably true that there's no hardware for it because there's no need for it. It either works or doesn't. With battery and USB C charging, it is necessary, because with battery you need to know when to stop charging and to stop drawing power from the battery and in the case of USB C, you need to negotiate for higher charging power, so you need censors. But it would be nice to have.

Answer (score 2):

> Doesn't the hardware provide the data?

Usually, that's exactly the case. Usually even, because the hardware doesn't even *sense* that.

Comment: Most PC power supplies do not report this as it would add cost and not much benefit - AC draw is just DC use multiplied byt the efficiency of the PSU, usually ~90% ish. Power failure (/PWRGOOD) is detected as the lower-voltage internal rail drops.  High end server gear _might_ do it but I suspect the main purpose of the AC node is for smart UPS units to report the status of the mains voltage - nearly all APC units can connect by one or more of USB, serial or network to tell connected machines about power failure, spikes, etc.